# Sample size equation based on clinical paper

Tags: sample-size, clinical-trials

Hoping this one is easy, but I've been struggling to try to find what approach is being used online.

I'm trying to replicate the powering of a clinical trial for research purposes based on the below paragraph - any input into what methodology is likely being used here would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

A planned sample size of 156 patients in the placebo
group and 104 patients in each of the AMG 334 groups
was expected to provide 80% power for a two-sided test
with a significance level of 0·05, assuming the same
effect size recorded in a randomized controlled trial of
topiramate of 1·6 days difference from placebo21 with a
common SD of 3·7 days and a 30% dropout.

The paper is an older Ph 2 trial titled: "Safety and effi cacy of AMG 334 for prevention of episodic
migraine: a randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled,
phase 2 trial"

Comment: Argh! The statement "a two-sided test" is about as uninformative as you can get.  Two possibilities are that it either refers to a two-sample independent t-test or a Wilcoxon test.

Comment: I don't think it is a t-test as I've tried that sample calc and it doesn't nearly match. I'm not familiar with WIlcoxon - do you mind providing the formula?

Comment: Another name for the test is Mann-Whitney U test - see here for details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann–Whitney_U_test.

Comment: I also suggest using the GPower software ( http://www.gpower.hhu.de  ) as it can perform sample size calculations for the Mann-Whitney U test.